# Importing an image to NetBeans' Java Swing GUI Builder

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I am trying to make a Java GUI using NetBeans' Swing GUI Builder. I want to import an image into my GUI. From research it seems to do this you must first create a JFrame form, then drag a JPanel onto that, then drag a JLabel on top of that. After putting your image in the project package folder, you then click on the JLabel and go to its properties, click the (...) beside "Icon," then select the image. For some reason when I try to run my GUI after inserting an image, the Java application icon appears in the taskbar, but no GUI appears on screen. After a few seconds, the Java application icon disappears from the taskbar, and the following error is displayed in the output box:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:232)
at com.mycompany.coachingintelligencepro4.TestFrame.initComponents(TestFrame.java:35)
at com.mycompany.coachingintelligencepro4.TestFrame.<init>(TestFrame.java:17)
at com.mycompany.coachingintelligencepro4.TestFrame$1.run(TestFrame.java:104)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Although, when making a GUI that does not involve importing an image, it runs perfectly fine, which leads me to believe there is a problem with the image importing process.

I am running Apache NetBeans IDE 18, on a MacBook Pro with MacOS Ventura 13.5.

This is the source code for my GUI class:

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/GUIForms/JFrame.java to edit this template
 */
package com.mycompany.coachingintelligencepro4;

/**
 *
 * @author ronellenbogen
 */
public class TestFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form TestFrame
     */
    public TestFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/mycompany/coachingintelligencepro4/download.jpg"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 475, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addContainerGap(1037, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(112, 112, 112)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 242, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(856, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main() {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

This is the source code for the project's main class:

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 */

package com.mycompany.coachingintelligencepro4;

/**
 *
 * @author ronellenbogen
 */
public class CoachingIntelligencePro4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestFrame.main();
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Slightly strange location, package `com.mycompany.coachingintelligencepro4` for your image. Does it exist and is the image in it?

Comment: Try placing your **resources** directory (folder) directly within the root of the `src` directory of your *Project*. Perhaps even have an path scheme like: **MyProjectName/src/resources/images**. When Importing Images from the Netbeans *Image Chooser* dialog, have them imported into the **MyProjectName/src/resources/images** directory or, manually copy/paste them there and then you can just select the one you want from the *Image Chooser* dialog.